# How to handle Rails params that may or may not exist, in controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is best practise for making a controller action that sometimes has key/values in `params` and sometimes doesn't?

I'm using a single endpoint for 2 similar purposes.

1. return items to be displayed **without** filters applied. No search terms from frontend.
2. return items to be displayed **with** filters applied. Yes search terms from frontend.

**Example of former:**

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"api/v1/items", "action"=>"search"} permitted: false>
```

**Example of latter:**

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"item"=>{"location"=>"New York"}, "controller"=>"api/v1/items", "action"=>"search"} permitted: false>
```

But it feels weird to detect whether search terms exist or not. I can do this:

```
if params.key?(:item)
  ...
end
```

But I started to wonder if combining 2 different pieces of logic in the same controller is an anti-pattern.

Additionally, strong params will just break.

```
if item_params
...
def item_params
  params.require(:item).permit(:location)
end
#=> param is missing or the value is empty: item
```

That said, combining them into a single endpoint simplifies the frontend logic. But I'm not sure if it's against convention.

Are there any best practises for this kind of situation?

Comment: Don't think there is a "best practice" answer.  Does the code work?  Is it testable? Is it easy to understand what it does and how it does it? If it these things are all true then it's good to go. Otherwise, it's time to revisit your approach.  In this instance,  a single if statement does what you want, is easy to test and understand its purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Use `fetch(:key_name, default_value)`[[1]](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-fetch) instead of require if the parameter is optional. For example:

```
def item_params
  params.fetch(:item, {}).permit(:location)
end
```

Using an empty hash as the default guarentees that you have an ActionController::Parameters instance present which is useful since it you can use accessors and #dig without getting nil errors:

```
if item_params[:location].present?
  # ...
end
```

Use `empty?` and `any?` to detect if the parameter is in fact empty. Having a single endpoint is not in itself a bad solution. The problem usually comes when you cram everything into the controller itself. Filters can be split into seperate objects such as models to move the logic to somewhere where it can be more easily tested.